# How can I add unfurl_links in Slack message

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack-block-kit

In the Slack message format example block below, how can I add `unfurl_link` option?

```js
{
  "type": "section",
  "text": {
    "type": "mrkdwn",
    "text": "New Paid Time Off request from <example.com|Fred Enriquez>\n\n<https://example.com|View request>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the snippet you posted is part of the `blocks` parameter, try adding the `unfurl_links` parameter with a value of `false` (outside the blocks):

```json
{
  "token": "your-slack-token",
  "channel": "#test-channel",
  "unfurl_links": false,
  "blocks": [{
    "type": "section",
    "text": {
      "type": "mrkdwn",
      "text": "New Paid Time Off request from <example.com|Fred Enriquez>\n\n<https://example.com|View request>"
    }
  }]
}
```